# 'PhotoSize' object has no attribute 'big_file_id'

Tags: python

Good evening. Sorry for the possibly stupid question. I am writing a telegram bot on video, for a gift. I want to make the bot send a photo with text on command, do everything as in the video, but the error 'PhotoSize' object has no attribute 'big_file_id' pops up. How to solve this please help

I tried changing the resolution of these photos

Comment: what video are you referring to? Also, please post your code

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]? We don't want to watch the video, but we need to see the code you wrote. See also [ask].